# Invalid .pkg file

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm having problems while sending a .pkg to Apple servers. ApplicationLoader says that the archives does not contain a valid in-app purchase content package.
I can't figure out what the problem is.

Am I building the package wrongly?

Thx

Comment: Hey, fellows, I could figure out the solution for this. At first I was building the package with PackageMaker, but now I gave a try to the Xcode built in feature in File->New Project->Othes->In-App Purchase and everything went ok. The only issue I faced was that it doesn't accept .svg files =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this tutorial can help you, it did it to me. http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Configuring_and_Creating_App_Store_Hosted_Content_for_iOS_6_In-App_Purchases

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this, which is much clear and detail: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_ios_6/changes_to_storekit/